# Material Date Picker Validation not working with FormBuilder.patchValue()

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form that requires a user to enter a date, the submit button is greyed out until they do so. This works perfectly until I have to edit the form. For some reason the validation isn't picking up my timestamp that populates the date field when I use `FormBuilder`'s `patchValue()` method like so:

In my page constructor I build my form (other fields removed for brevity):

```
this.submitForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  submissionReleaseDate: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Then in my `ngOnInit()` I query to get the releaseDate from my database and then run:

```
    this.submitForm.patchValue({
      submissionReleaseDate: moment.unix(this.submission.submissionReleaseDate).utc(),
    })
```

All the other fields from my form are validated (when checking the classes added by angular I see ng-valid) except for the date field (where the class remains ng-invalid) until I type a character into that field.

Here's what it looks like when I load the edit page, as you can see the submit button is greyed out even though the fields are populated:

[image]

Here's my material date picker html:

```
<input matInput [min]="date" formControlName="submissionReleaseDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

And my `module.ts` for that page:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    NgAisModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS},
    { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } }
  ],
  declarations: [SubmitPage]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WELL...it took me about a year but I finally figured it out. Turns out, on page load, I was receiving a `matDatepickerMin` validator error. This was because my `[min]="date"` variable I was using was defined as this:

`this.date = moment().utc().startOf('day').format();`

While it needed to be this:

`this.date = moment().utc().startOf('day').format("X");`

Since the min date format was different than the date format I was using to `patchValue`, it was causing the error. Phew!

Answer (score 0):

So apparently Reactive forms do not work nicely with **ChangeDetectionPush** are you using **ChangeDetectionPush**? 
If so:

I know this is not optimal, but I found **ChangeDetectorRef** to solve this issue, forcing the UI to refresh (It does not know your modal changed since **ChangeDetectionPush** is on)

*Constructor:*

```
constructor(
  private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
)
```

*Updating data:*

```
 this.submitForm.patchValue({
      submissionReleaseDate: moment.unix(this.submission.submissionReleaseDate).utc(),
    }) 

 this.cdr.detectChanges(); // This is magic
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't seem to resolve, I added the `detectChanges()` after the patchValue with no luck :/